# Need to unload an external swf from Array..cs4 as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cs4

I have to turn some paintings into an animated flash SWF/game(s) and the someone else will turn it into an app.

I have an opening animation - this leads to a menu, where you can selct a few things - but right now the animation just plays through to the frame where the user has chosen Games.

I've made a game menu - when you select a game - the button loads the specific game into an empty MC (Called emptymc - instance name emptymc_MC)

The game loads up and covers the whole screen, apart from a menu bar on the top layer - which sits underneath at all times in the app. I haven't made these options yet - but it will most likely be a sound toggle - visit website - buy full app.

Ideally, I would want this to finish to the last frame and then unload or remove itself. Meanwhile, the SWF is revealed underneath. My problem is that I can't get rid of my imported SWF, Even when I load a new version into the loader.

```
stop(); 

bee.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click);
function Click( event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(currentFrame+1);
}

bee.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f);
function f(e:Event):void{
var movieArray:Array = ["howmanybees1", "howmanybees2", "howmanybees3",];
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
var index:int = movieArray.length * Math.random();
var url:String = movieArray[index] + '.swf'; 
trace("Attempting to load", url); 
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete); 
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError); 
addChild(loader); 

function loaderComplete(e:Event):void {     
    trace("Successfully loaded", url);
    } function loaderIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {     
    trace("Failed to load", url);    
}  
    }
```

** EDIT **

Here is my current source code:

```
stop();


  bee.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click);

  function Click(event: MouseEvent): void {
      gotoAndPlay(currentFrame + 1);
  }


  bee.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f);

  function f(e: Event): void {
      var movieArray: Array = ["howmanybees1", "howmanybees2", "howmanybees3", "howmanybees4", "howmanybees5", ];
      var loader: Loader = new Loader();
      var index: int = movieArray.length * Math.random();
      var url: String = movieArray[index] + '.swf';
      trace("Attempting to load", url);
      loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError);
      stage.addEventListener("UnloadGame", unloadGame);
      addChild(loader);


      function loaderComplete(e: Event): void {
          trace("Successfully loaded", url);
      }

      function loaderIOError(e: IOErrorEvent): void {
          trace("Failed to load", url);
      }

      function unloadGame(e: Event): void {
          trace("unloaded at last", url);
          loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
          loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError);
          loader.removeEventListener("UnloadGame", unloadGame);
          removeChild(loader);
          loader.unloadAndStop();
      }
  }
  sheepgamebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click2);

  function Click2(event: MouseEvent): void {
      gotoAndPlay(currentFrame + 1);
  }


  sheepgamebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, i);

  function i(e: Event): void {
      var movieArray: Array = ["sheep1"];
      var loader: Loader = new Loader();
      var index: int = movieArray.length * Math.random();
      var url: String = movieArray[index] + '.swf';
      trace("Attempting to load", url);
      loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
      loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError);
      stage.addEventListener("UnloadGame", unloadGame);
      addChild(loader);

      function loaderComplete(e: Event): void {
          trace("Successfully loaded", url);
      }

      function loaderIOError(e: IOErrorEvent): void {
          trace("Failed to load", url);
      }

      function unloadGame(e: Event): void {
          trace("unloaded at last", url)
          loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
          loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError);
          loader.removeEventListener("UnloadGame", unloadGame);
          removeChild(loader);
          loader.unloadAndStop();
      }
  }
```

Comment: You question is much, much too wordy.  Consider editing it to just include the bare minimum needed to understand your issue.  You'll get more people making it to the end that way.

Comment: Thankyou - Appreciate the tip..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a new swf doesn't affect a previously loaded swf at all (even if using the same variable).  You need to tell Flash what to do.

When finished with your loaded content, you should do three things:

1. Remove it from the display:

   ```
   removeChild(loader);
   ```
2. Remove any event listeners that aren't weakly referenced:

   ```
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError);
   ```
3. Unload the loader:

   ```
   loader.unloadAndStop();
   ```

Once those things are done, you can reuse the variable and load in new content.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of having your child swf trigger an unload:

*Inside the main timeline of your Loaded SWF Somewhere*

```
function unloadGame():void {
    if(stage) stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("UnloadGame"));
}
```

*In your main swf*

```
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));            
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete); 
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError); 
stage.addEventListener("UnloadGame", unloadGame);
addChild(loader); 

function unloadGame(e:Event):void {
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete); 
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOError); 
    loader.removeEventListener("UnloadGame", unloadGame);
    removeChild(loader); 
    loader.unloadAndStop();
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. But - how do I let Flash know that the ext SWF is finished? I think the ideal thing would be - if the child could close itself - all games will roll out off screen at the end - seems a neat way to work with the multiple games/swfs that will be being used.    Excuse any lack of understanding - I'm new to AS3 and haven't used Flash in yesrs -

Comment: That depends greatly on the nature of your loaded swf.  Events are a good way to go. I'll update the answer to show you an example.

Comment: Wow. That's amazing. I literally spent a whole day copying codes from various forums and chopping and changing them and trying to get them to work... You come along... bang, nailed it one!!!   Incredible work - thankyou. It always amazes me how you internet heroes are always there to rescue the lost and confused - Internet angels...haha. 

Thank you ever so much - This is also the first code I have copied and pasted that hasn't bought any errors on output.

I'm going to give myself some time to try and undertsand the code and why this one in particular worked..  :)  Thanks again..

Comment: Hey. Bit  of a post script here - but I've created the second game - It loads fine, but doesn't unload. However, the first movie/game does. Do I need to tweak your code, above, to work for a second and subsequent games? thx

Comment: Are you sure the second one is dispatching the `"UnloadGame"` event?  Put a break point or trace statement in the `unloadGame` method and see it's ever reached for your second game.  The code isn't specific to any one file.

Comment: Ok. I popped it underneath... 

    loader.unloadAndStop();
 trace("unloaded the movie");

It may not be in the right place - the first movie (and all 5 arrays of it) all load and unload. But the second movie doesn't. But the output doesn't tell me that the first movie unloaded, even though it did.

Comment: put simply - there is no output message to say anything unloaded

Comment: And your using the the debug player and have trace statements enabled?

Comment: Not debug player - will look into that - but trace statements are working elsewhere - in the same app

Comment: Try putting the trace statement at the start of the function.

Comment: Ok. So I've screwed up. When putting this  .    function unloadGame():void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event("UnloadGame"));
}        into the last frames on movie 1 - I must have pasted over  stop() - so the movie 1 was just playing a load of empty frames that I hadn't cleaned up - I noticed because I left it on the test movie and it must have looped back on itself.  Which means, sadly, the original code didn't work.. Or at least the way I set it up didn't work..

Comment: Maybe try adding/listening to the event on the `stage`.  I updated the code.

Comment: I've added the current script below - maybe it's obvious from that where I'm going wrong.. thx

Comment: can you post a link to one of your child swf's, then I can test it properly.

Comment: I will - it isn't online anywhere yet - as it won't end up on there - but I will post the swf somewhere and let you know the link.  Just a thought, in the meantime,   could the reason for it not working be that it is a button calling the event in ? Or that the unload function is being called inside of the button 'section' in the AS?

Comment: Yes,  the unload event needs to be dispatched on the main timeline's scope (though if you updated it to dispatch/listen on the stage it shouldn't matter) .    You could try this:    `MovieClip(root).dispatchEvent(new Event("UnloadGame"))`;   - you could also try making it bubble by passing `true` as the second parameter in a new event:   `new Event("UnloadGame",true);`   That will make the event bubble up to the stage no matter where it is dispatched **as long as it's dispatched on a object that is visible on the stage**

Comment: HI. Apologies for the long delay. I've had to move on with the app and work on other games - buut your code works when I use it on a newly consructed SWF - importing another new SWF.  I'll hopefully get to fix my original file soon.. thanks again for your help.